# Unable to use meta_query between currency values when value is over 1 million

Tags: meta-query

I am trying to add a `meta_query` that searches for values of the field `price` that are between two different values. As long as the values stay below $1 million it works great. However, as soon as one of the values goes above 7 figures it only searches for values as if the last digit was omitted (so $1,000,000 turns into $100,00).

**CODE:**

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( "$400,000", "$1,200,000" ),
        'type' => 'CHAR',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
```

Removing/adding commas and/or decimals does not fix the issue. Values are stored in the DB in the same format as the values in the array above.

**UPDATE**

By changing the above to `'type' = 'NUMERICAL'` I was able to get this to work. The problem I am having now is that I need to use variables to populate the array and when I do this I get all posts that match the rest of the criteria. I'm certain it is something to do with the data-type but I'm not sure what to use seeing that the variables and the values in the db contain '$' and ','.

So, here's what I have now:

**VARIABLES**

```
$min = "$300,000";
$max = "$1,200,000";
```

**QUERY**

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( $min, $max ),
        'type' => 'NUMERICAL',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
```

Comment: What about storing and searching on them without the $?

Comment: Values are stored in the DB with the $. The above works if the second value is changed to a value below $1 million (ie, $999,00).

Comment: if the DB do not contain numbers then you can't use numeric compare. this is actually an SQL question

Comment: @MarkKaplun Numeric works on the first query above. The problem now is when the value are stored in a variable. DB contains values such as '$599,000' or '$1,149,000'.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, apparently my solution faces the same problem when the query contains values such as '$599,000' or '$1,149,000.

so far, the only solution so far was cleaning the database imported data values to INT/UNSIGNED (even though, meta_value is saved as TEXT).

However, the meta ordering by value still don't work quite as it should.

**Original suggestion:**

Working with real state properties search by value I've faced the same problem.

I was able to fix this very same issue using compare type CHAR and separating my meta query args as follow:

```
  $meta_query = array();

  if ($_GET['min'] && $_GET['max']) {
  
    $meta_query[] =  array(
        'key'     => 'value',
        'value'   => '$'.$_GET['min'], // PREPEND '$' TO COMPARE STRINGS IN "$2.000.000,00" BRL FORMAT
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
        'compare' => '>=',
    );
    $meta_query[] =  array(
        'key'     => 'valor',
        'value'   => '$'.$_GET['max'], 
        'type'          => 'CHAR',
        'compare' => '<=',
    );
}
```

Then build the rest of my query:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'      => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'post_type'        => 'imovel',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);

if ($_GET['cod']) {
    $args['title'] = $_GET['cod'];
}

//   dump_die($args);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```